# PhpStorm ignores symlinked composer vendor library

Tags: php, composer-php, phpstorm, symlink

Composer has a very handy feature that is `path` type repositories. Its relevance for me is that I can add my own libraries as `path` repositories to a project, which symlinks them to my local library repository, thus allowing me to easily track and commit library changes when debugging and developing my project that uses them.

This, however, doesn't agree with PhpStorm, it seems; the corresponding symlinked folder in `vendor` is listed as an unknown file type and its contents are not browsed; as such, I have no static analysis of my included library.

Is there a way to use symlinked composer repos with PhpStorm?

Comment: That's an unexpected behavior, IDE shouldn't show them as "unknown file type". Unfortunately can't say why this is happening. It's best to submit this to our tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue and investigate in details

Comment: @Dmitrii after a little more research the problem seems to reside in https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/353 - it's a WSL mount that's causing the problems w/ symlinks, I will do some more research but it may be unrelated to PHPStorm

Comment: Thanks for sharing this

Comment: @Dmitrii so to check this I installed storm in the WSL container via Xming (which runs terribly btw), and there the symlinked libraries are listed as "Invalid link" for now, will explore some more.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find a way to work around this: by going to `Settings` > `Language & Frameworks` > `PHP` > `Include Path` I can add paths to the original directories that Composer symlinks against. However, this is very error-prone (I have to remember to sync these settings to the settings in `composer.json` and remove them altogether when testing for release), so I'm still looking for a better answer.